# How get country and city using IP address in PHP

Tags: php

```
I am trying  to get country and city using ip address in php.My code is given below.
```

I got the output.Any body give any solution for these issue?I got the out put like these way   IP Address:- 127.0.0.1
      City:- Not Define
      Country:- Not Define

```
 <?php
 /*Get user ip address*/
 $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

/*Get user ip address details with geoplugin.net*/
$geopluginURL='http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip_address;
$addrDetailsArr = unserialize(file_get_contents($geopluginURL)); 

/*Get City name by return array*/
$city = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_city']; 

/*Get Country name by return array*/
$country = $addrDetailsArr['geoplugin_countryName'];

/*Comment out these line to see all the posible details*/
/*echo '<pre>';
print_r($addrDetailsArr);
die();*/

if(!$city){
$city='Not Define';
}if(!$country){
$country='Not Define';
 }
echo '<strong>IP Address</strong>:- '.$ip_address.'<br/>';
echo '<strong>City</strong>:- '.$city.'<br/>';
echo '<strong>Country</strong>:- '.$country.'<br/>';
?>
```

Comment: 1) try it with a real IP, 2) read the documentation for the MaxMind Lite database

Comment: @symcbean: 127.0.0.1 is a real IP.

Comment: @shilna: You've misunderstood how IP addresses work and what `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` does. You need to obtain your WAN IP in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the request come from an IP address on the Internet. Sending it from your localhost loopback network interface isn't going to give the server an IP address that has a location in any database.